# Replace obj file geometric vertex with real coordinates 3D coordinates

Tags: mesh, vertex

I have a actual plane with known 3D coordinates of it's four corners relative to a landmark. It's coordinates are:

Front left corner: -32.5100  128.2703  662.2551
Front right corner: 65.2244  131.0850  656.1088
Back left corner: -23.4983  129.0271  838.3724
Back right corner: 74.1135  131.4294  833.4199

I am now creating a 3D obj file plane by using blender which has a image as texture mapped on it. By following the tutorial about adding texture on a plane using blender, I get both my obj file and mtl file shows below. I tried to directly replace the geometric vertex of the obj file to my own coordinates, but the coordinates are not connected in meshlab. Any idea about how to modify the obj file?

Thanks,

OBJ File:

```
# Blender v2.76 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib planePhantom.mtl
o Plane
v -0.088000 0.000000 0.049250
v 0.088000 0.000000 0.049250
v -0.088000 0.000000 -0.049250
v 0.088000 0.000000 -0.049250
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000 
vt 0.000000 1.000000 
vn 0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
usemtl Material.001
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 4/3/1 3/4/1
```

MTL file:

```
# Blender MTL File: 'None'
# Material Count: 1

newmtl Material.001
Ns 96.078431
Ka 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
Kd 0.640000 0.640000 0.640000
Ks 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
Ke 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
Ni 1.000000
d 1.000000
illum 0
map_Kd IMG_0772_cropped_unsharpmask_100_4_0.jpeg
```

The plane shows in meshlab before replacing:

[image: correct 3D view]

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it turns out be that the order for connecting vertex is wrong and I have already figured it out